# Build simple wireless door (open/close) sensor with Arduino or Attiny84/87

Tags: wireless, proximity-sensor

I have a spare Arduino uno, a few Attiny84 and a few Attiny87.
In my Raspberry PI I have installed a RFM12Pi and have a spare RFM12b to use with Arduino.
Last piece I have in the drawer is a sonic sensor (HC-SR04).

I would like to build the cheapest possible door sensor but I am far from being an expert.

What would be the best idea to assemble those pieces and realize a system that sends a signal to my raspberry pi each time the door is opened / closed?

If interfacing those components is hard for a newbie I also thought about buying something similar that could simplify the project:

http://www.adafruit.com/products/1097

What is the cheapest, easiest and low power solution?

Thanks for your time and patience and sorry if the question is not the best you've ever read: I am trying to learn :)

Comment: Is there a specific bit of the problem you need help with?  Right now it looks like you need the whole project designed, which might be off-topic.  See if you can narrow the question down if you already have experience of some parts (e.g. the microcontrollers you mentioned).

Comment: Magnetic switch.

Comment: Perfect answer, Ignacio!
Make it such and I'll give you the points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To comunicate between the raspberry and arduino, there is a nice and cheap module (nRF24l01).. I already used it and I counsel to use.. there are already libraries and a lot of tutorial for them on the internet.. it's just need some search